# GCP Equivalent for AWS Landing zone solution

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS provides a solution called Landing Zone to jumpstart cloud adoption for an enterprise. This solution is based on AWS best practices. It provides a starting point by auto creating multiple accounts and configures shared services such as logging, monitoring etc. Is there an equivalent solution for GCP ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ones to choose from

- [Google Cloud Foundation Toolkit](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-example-foundation) is a comprehensive example built on terraform
- [Google Cloud Foundation Fabric](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-foundation-fabric) has a landing zone blueprint, and also comes with modules for standing up common workloads quickly
- [Landing Zone Construction Kit](https://landingzone.meshcloud.io) is a modular, multi-cloud landing zone framework built on terraform modules covering AWS, Azure and GCP

The core principles behind landing zones transfer very well between all (public) cloud providers, the essential challenges are always the same (tenant management, logging/auditing, resource hierarchy, basic policies/guardrails etc.).